# LSTM + Attention Implementation with undefined timestep shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I'm trying to implement a stacked LSTM with attention with varying timesteps.  I mainly based it off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812351/keras-attention-layer-over-lstm), [this](https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-attention-mechanism), and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1472).  These implementations, however, assume fixed timesteps.  The model runs, but I'm not sure if this is doing what I think it's doing.  Futhermore, I'm not sure how to extract timestep-level importance from this model.

```
# stacked LSTM
for i, n_hidden in enumerate(hidden_units):
        x = LSTM(n_hidden, name='lstm_%i' % (i + 1), **lstm_kwargs)(x)

# flatten RNN output over time
context = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_hidden, activation='tanh'))(x)
context = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_flatten(x))(context)

context = Dense(1, activation='tanh')

# turn context attention into probability distribution using softmax (enforce that attentions to sum up to 1)
context = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(context)
context = RepeatVector(n_hidden)(context)
context = Permute([2,1])(context)

# multiply LSTM output with ts-wise attention
attention = Multiply()([x, context])

# make output time distributed
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_shape, activation=output_activation), name='output')(attention)

# initialize model wrapper
model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=output)
```

What I think my code is doing:

[image: What I think this code is doing]

Image of the attention unit is from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2rWgXJBZhU&t=203s) video.

Comment: By the _varying time steps_, you mean that the decoder can generate more than one output symbol at a time?

Comment: thanks for the response-- varying time step meaning that the timestep dimension is `None`

Comment: So input timesteps can be varying but how about the output? In your current design it will output just 1 value for the whole  sequence (TimeDistributed on the last layer doesn't  make sense)

Comment: This is a sequence-to-sequence model.  The network should output one value for each timestep.

Comment: That makes sense  but will require complex masking logic to prevent future information from leaking into the current timestep. This is possible with eager execution which is not available in standalone Keras but is now an option in tensorflow

Comment: Makes sense.  Could you point me to some of these resources via tensorflow?  I actually did notice these future info leakages in the current implementation of the network.

Answer (score -2):

This cannot be done because of the limitation of tensor operation. Normally, when you packed the data for training, you need to pack them to a tensor, which means that their sequence length should be equal for all data.

If you want to make a dynamic timestep, you need to implement your code using a non-vectorization method, which is very inefficient (imagine you need to do for-loop every time you multiply matrix instead of using matrix multiplication).

Normally, when we are dealing with different sequence length data, the data is zero-padded and mask the zero out.